How does exhaustive listing interact with quirky cases?
It is well known that subjective-が can have exhaustive-listing properties, implying that the sentence applies no further within the universe of discourse than the subject:

私がした。-> “I'm the one who did it”

However, how does this transfer onto a nominative object, for instance:

私はあなたが好きだ。

Can this object still have exhaustive listing function and thus mean “You're the one I love.”, and what of a dative subject:

私に分かっている。

Can this mean “I'm the one who understands it.” opposed to merely “I understand it.”?

I'm not sure what you intended with the last sentence. It has no が in it.

@aguijonazo I was wondering if dative subjects could also indicate exhaustive listing, or if only nominative subjects can.

There are only "nominative objects" and "dative subjects" after translating into an English frame of reference.  For instance, grammatically speaking, the に in 私にわかっている marks the agent.

@EiríkrÚtlendi What makes you say that? There are grammatical tests in Japanese that show how they behave subject-like or object-like syntactically.

@DariusJahandarie, I wrote a longer post about this at https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4991/dative-subjects/94546#94546.

At least in general, exhausting listing is a function of が. It's not related (again, in general) to grammatical role of が-phrase in a sentence. So the question of the title looks off to me.

@sundowner - How do you distinguish a function of が and a grammatical role of a が-phrase in a sentence?

@aguijonazo As I understand it, the question asks if other subject-phrase using particles other than が means exhaustive listing. What I meant is "exhaustive listing" is something attached to が and not to being a subject. For me, it is not about distinguishing function and grammatical role, rather it is just a matter of whether or not が is used at all.


私はあなたが好きだ。

The grammatical terms aside, this sentence in itself doesn't mean "you are the one I like." If you want it to mean that, you would have to stress あなた in speech.
The first が in the sentence below does have the exhaustive listing property, but its effect is on 私, of course.

私があなたが好きだ。



私に分かっている。

This is not a very natural sentence by itself though it may appear in a dependent clause as in:

私に分かっていることは〜だ。

As a standalone sentence, what you meant would be expressed by either:

私は分かっている。

or

私が分かっている。

This が has the exhaustive listing property as you would expect.
By the way, the following sentence sounds natural.

私に分かる。

There clearly is a hidden subject here and that thing is understandable to me. I don't think this "dative subject" thing applies here.
